# Using plymouth theme on login screen

Tags: 18.04, login, plymouth

I've set my Plymouth theme in the standard way, by copying and modifying the existing `ubuntu-logo` Plymouth theme. This now displays as the splash when powering up and down.

Is it possible to use the same Plymouth theme at login in place of the background, or modified and reapplied in some other way? If so, how?

Comment: you want the same image (single image) that is used for plymouth as login screen background?

Comment: Not the same image, but the entire script, including the animation produced by the script - I know how to use the appropriate css to simply display the background image. Mine has a simple animation which is scripted, and I'd like that to display too!

Comment: I doubt is that possible? also I doubt is there a way to use .gif file as background

Comment: @PRATAP That's a real shame :(